# Background color not working inside table in Outlook 2013 mail

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2013

when apply background color in parent div of table then color not apply in outlook 2013 mail

```
<div style="background-color:red">
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
            Background color not applying
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

when apply background color in table then color is apply in outlook 2013 mail

```
<div>
   <table style="background-color:red">
     <tr>
        <td>
            Background color is applying
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

is there any way to apply color in parent div?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know Outlook uses Word for rendering email bodies.

Two HTML elements that support a subset of the cascading style sheets properties are called out: `DIV` and `P`. `DIV` and `P` support a subset of Word–supported cascading style sheet and are defined in the following article by the term COREEXTENDED:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing this is Outlook 2013 Windows but have you can try wrappig the div in a  and apply a bgcolor OUTSIDE the style="".
Or simply try the bgcolor in general.